# JS не выводит на страницу массив с большим количеством элементов

Tags: javascript

Такой вопрос.
Есть функция вывода всех простых чисел, до какого то n-ого числа, которое я ввожу. Вывод на страницу происходит нормально примерно до n = 3000000 (3 миллиона). Используется алгоритм Решета Эратосфена.
Если я ввожу число больше, то ничего не выводит на страницу, хотя если посмотреть через devtools div,в который выводятся числа, они в нем есть. В чем может быть проблема и решаема ли она?

```
(function () {
 "use strict";

 window.numberPrimes = function (input) {
   var OUTPUT = "";
   if (typeof input === "object") {
     if (isNaN(input.msg) === true) {
       OUTPUT = "Введен неккоректный символ";
       return OUTPUT;
     }
   } else {
     return;
   }
   var num = BigInt(input.msg);
   var deletes = [];
   var primes = [];

   for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
     if (!deletes[i]) {
       primes.push(i);
       for (let j = i * 2; j <= num; j += i) {
         deletes[j] = true;
       }
     }
   }
   OUTPUT = primes;
   return OUTPUT;
 };
})();


document.getElementById("message").addEventListener("input", function () {
 var itsValue = this.value;
 document.getElementById("output").textContent = numberPrimes({
   msg: itsValue,
 });
});

document.getElementById("output").textContent = numberPrimes({
 msg: document.getElementById("message").value,
});
```

Comment: Слишком мало ждёте?

Comment: на 3.8 млн довольно быстро выводит результат, при 3.9 прождал 3 минуты ничего не вывело, при этом сама страница не зависла (в консоль выводится массив с числами, а на саму страницу нет)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, html страница имеет ограничение в ширину, поэтому помог перенос чисел на новые строки через word-wrap: break-word;